# How to add Wishlist button field in views in drupal 7?

Tags: views, commerce

I am working on commerce site. In my site I have 3 views & each view have display 3 products. If user can first visit the product then user get the wishlist button but I want to show "add to cart" or "wishlist" or "buy" button with all the products so user can directly purchase, no need to visit.

I already created **Relation : "Content: Referenced products"** & add **Field : "Commerce Product: Add to Cart form"**. But no button show below product. Please help to solve. Thanks

Comment: have you added the filter "Content: Type (= Product display)"

Comment: Yes.. I have already did.. but it shows nothing... @Bala

Comment: I also have same problem...I can see it in single product page.But how it is possible to display in view ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most straightforward way is to use views to render your product display nodes. Instead of "fields" choose "node" and then choose your display mode. Perhaps use [display_suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to get more advanced control over what your products look like when rendered.

Sidenote, [there's a great video I created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYMd6WDqxKY) that shows you how to use `hook_form_alter` to move the wishlist button around.