# How do I show product attribute fields in a view?

Tags: commerce

I'm having difficulty with what seems straight forward and have tried many Drupal Commerce extra modules. Can anyone advise on showing product attributes in a add-to-cart form?

I have product types: 
- "product" and 
- "boat checkout"

And "boat checkout" products: 
- 1/2 day 
- full day

And node types: 
- basic page
- boat 
- boat reservation

I'm not able to get boat product attributes showing in the add form nor in the checkout view, despite attribute settings on Despite visibility on /admin/commerce/products/types/boat-checkout/fields.  I'd prefer using a view to keep the site simple (and not creating 2 nodes to display 2 products).

Separately, can product attributes be saved/ shown on orders??  Very hard letting users change or view attributes.

Comment: In your view, perhaps you need to add a RELATIONSHIP of some sort, in order for the attributes to become available in add fields.

Comment: No luck with views. I did get custom attributes showing on the display node form with [commerce_custom_product](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_custom_product). It doesn't appear they're captured in the saved order though. I don't see history for the user's attribute choices.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer borrowed from my answer over here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131595/how-to-add-wishlist-button-field-in-views-in-drupal-7/188242#188242).

Most straightforward way is to use views to render your product display nodes. Instead of "fields" choose "node" and then choose your display mode. Perhaps use [display_suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to get more advanced control over what your products look like when rendered.